# C++ winsockets threading issue

Tags: c++, multithreading

I made a pretty simple C++ socket server. I'm trying to spawn a thread each time a new client connects (so reading can be done in parallel).

```
void Server::start(void){
    for(;;){ 
        Logger::Log("Now accepting clients");
        int client;
        struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
        size_t addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
        client = accept(this->m_socket, (sockaddr*)&client_addr, 0);
        if(client != SOCKET_ERROR){
            Logger::Log("New client connected!");
            StateObject client_object(client, this);
            this->clients.push_back(&client_object);

            std::stringstream stream;
            stream<<this->clients.size()<<" clients online";
            Logger::Log(const_cast<char*>(stream.str().c_str()));
            std::thread c_thread(std::bind(&StateObject::read, std::ref(client_object)));
            //c_thread.join(); //if I join the child, new clients won't be accepted until the previous thread exits
        }
    }
}
```

Reading method in client class:

```
void StateObject::read(){
    Logger::Log("Now reading");
    for(;;){
        int bytesReceived = recv(this->socket, buffer, 255, 0);
        if(bytesReceived > 0){
            Logger::Log(const_cast<char*>(std::string("Received: " + std::string(buffer).substr(0, bytesReceived)).c_str()));
        }else if(bytesReceived == 0){
            Logger::Log("Client gracefully disconnected");
            break;
        }else{
            Logger::Log("Could not receive data from remote host");
            break;
        }
    }
    Server * server = reinterpret_cast<Server*>(parent);
    server->removeClient(this);
}
```

Currently, after a client connects an exception is thrown: 
[image: Screenshot]

**Why and when has abort been triggered?**
Please note that this happens when the child thread hasn't joined the main thread. On the other case, the "flow" goes expectedly synchronous (the current client thread has to exit so that the loop can continue to accept the next client).

**Notes:**

- Since I am tied to Windows, I'm unable to fork child tasks - I am also not a fan of Cygwin. Asynchronous win32 methods seem to complicate things that is why I avoid them.
- **[C++ std::thread reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/)**
- Tests have been done through **Telnet**

Comment: You either need to detach the thread or join it before it goes out of scope.. Otherwise `std::thread` calls `std::terminate` in its destructor.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that it has to be detached manually. Please add your statement as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to detach the thread or join it before it goes out of scope.. Otherwise std::thread calls std::terminate in its destructor.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/~thread/